# Calculate difference in negative floating numbers with bc

Tags: command-line, numeric-data, paste, bc

I want to calculate the difference between two negative floating numbers and subsequently check if the result is below a certain threshold. The numbers are stored in the `file.dat`, since this calculation will be done many times the calculation has to rely on getting the values directly from a file without manual formatting. The `file.dat` looks for example like this.

`-.63354975E+03
-.63354982E+03`

Now since bash can't handle floats I've tried `bc` in the following way:

`paste -sd- file.dat | bc >> file.dat`

The `paste` command turns the input into

`-.63354975E+03--.63354982E+03`

`bc` should subract them, however I get the error message `(standard_in) 1: syntax error`. I could use `sed` to change one number to positive and then add them, but is there a way to do it directly with `bc`?

---

A different problem occurs when I use `paste -sd+ file.dat | bc >> file.dat`. This should add the numbers, the result is however `4.932900412`, way off the expected `1267.09957`. When I type in the calculation with the numbers formatted as `-633.54975+-633.54982` I get the expected result. So it seems `bc` does not process numbers with exponents properly. Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: The problem is the lack of whitespace (to delimit the numbers into separate tokens) I think - you could try replacing `paste -sd-` by `pr -T -S' - ' -2` (`pr` allows *string* delimiters, whereas AFAIK `paste` only allows a single character)

Comment: Alright, this does the trick, but the second problem kicks in. The result from the example is 6.000000070 instead of 0.00007. When I change the number format to -633.54... the result is correct. Do you know how to resolve this? Then the answer would be complete.

Comment: for number format with expopnent see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882611/how-to-get-bc-to-handle-numbers-in-scientific-aka-exponential-notation There is an additional problem when you use the same file `file.dat` both as input argument and for output redirection.

Comment: @steeldriver Alright in this case please formulate an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: If you're going to use `sed` to modify the exponent, then you may as well use it for inserting the operator as well e.g. `sed -e '$!N;s/\n/ - /' -e '...'`

Answer (score 0):

`awk` solution:

```
awk 'NR==1{a=$0};NR==2{b=$0};END{print (a)-(b)}' file.dat
```